# JSON and AJAX send string NOT whole page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am having some trouble with JSON, I have an ajax thing that sends one variable over to a php file. The php file takes the variable, grabs a row of a database based on that variable and **HOPEFULLY** (*someday*) will send it back my javascript so I can plug that value into a function.

However when it sends back information it comes out as the entire page html (minus php of course) and I can see that logged in the consul. I know that i need to parse the information coming from the PHP file but as of now I can't figure out how to get ONLY a string of relevant data sent back so that I can parse it (with the jquery way)

Here's the code :-)

```
var request2 = $.ajax({
url : "geturl.php",
data : {intermediate_integer : intermediate_integer},
type : 'post'
}).done(function(data) {
console.log(data);

var gotfrom = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

console.log(gotfrom.url);
});
```

and here is what my PHP file looks like

```
<html>
<head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script><script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/scripts/json/json.js"></script><script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/scripts/json/json2.js"></script><script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/scripts/json/json_parse.js"></script><script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/scripts/json/json_parse_state.js"></script>
<script src="http://s199881165.onlinehome.us/transfem/scripts/json/cycle.js"></script></head>

<body> <?
$now_video_var = $_POST['intermediate_integer'];
$list_num_adjust = $now_video_var +1 ; 

$z=0;

$user= "dbasdfasdf04";
$pass= "nasdfass";
$numbah = 1;

try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=db2asdfsadf.net;dbname=db3asdf04', $user, $pass);
} 
catch (Exception $e) {
die("Unable to connect: " . $e->getMessage());
}

$seleccion = 'SELECT url, listnum FROM vim_playlist12';
foreach ($dbh->query($seleccion) as $row) 
{  
$URLnumeral[$z] = $row['url'];
$z++;   
}

$sending_you_are_elle = $URLnumeral[$now_video_var];  

?> 
<script>

var send_end_this ={ "url" : "<? echo $sending_you_are_elle ;?>" }
alert(send_end_this.url);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

AAANNnNNnnnd here's what I get back from my consul:

```
SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '<'
```

which.... duh. I know I am doing something majorly wrong here. But I can't seem to google up the answer for myself.

Tally, Ho!

Will

Comment: Why catch an exception only to use `die`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to include JavaScript JSON files on the php side to parse JSON, but that doesn't make any sense.  PHP has `json_encode` to convert PHP constructs to a JSON string that you can then echo.  Get rid of everything outside of `<?php` and `?>`.  Your file will look something like this:

```
<?php
$now_video_var = $_POST['intermediate_integer'];
/* snip */
$sending_you_are_elle = $URLnumeral[$now_video_var];
echo json_encode($sending_you_are_ell);
exit;
```

Comment: Might want to add a content type header of `application/json`

Comment: @Phil the effects of that could be undesirable as that will return already parsed JSON and make the `parseJSON` call invalid.  I guess that's all right but it is something to be aware of

Comment: Yes, I'd remove the `parseJSON()` call in the JS

Comment: WOW, clarity abound. Ok. First thanks so much for that. I did as you suggested and came out with     "{\"URL\" , \"64559982\"}"     this as my html output.... and I mean exactly that with the "s (inside and outside) and the \s and all! Here's the code:


 `$sending_you_are_elle = '{"URL" , "' .  $URLnumeral[$now_video_var] . '"}' ; 
 
 $json_son = json_encode($sending_you_are_elle);
 
echo $json_son;`

Comment: @WillDelphia if `$sending_you_are_elle` is already a JSON formatted string then you don't need to call `json_encode` on it